# How to stop player from walking off while descending a ladder in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, scripting

So I want my player to be able to travel up and down ladders without falling off unintentionally. Climbing up is easy enough, just let them walk forward against a wall and they'll collide and stay still but when they descend using the 'back' button they will start descending very briefly but immediately walk off the ladder. Disabling the player script temporarily is a messy process so I wanted to know what a good alternative is.

I'm using `transform` to raise and lower my player in the `ladderScript` and to move it in the `playerScript`.

Script (amended for brevity)

```
public class LadderScript : MonoBehaviour {

    private playerScript pScript; //<--These both contain the colliding players script...
    private Collider collided; //<---- ...and collider when Update runs
    private bool triggerStay; //used to prevent Update from running while there is no contact

    void Start()
    {
        triggerStay = false;
    }

    ...

    void Update() //Runs once per collider that is touching the player every frame
    {
        if (triggerStay) {
            if (collided.CompareTag ("Player")) { //A player is touching the ladder
                /*  
                if (!pScript.getIsGrounded ()) {    //Ineffective
                    pScript.enabled = false;
                } else if (pScript.getIsGrounded ()) {
                    pScript.enabled = true;
                }
                    */
                if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") < 0) { // Player should go down
                    collided.transform.Translate (0, -.1f, 0);
                } else if (Input.GetAxis ("Vertical") > 0) //Player should go up
                        collided.transform.Translate (0, .1f, 0);
            }
        }
    }

     ...

}
```

Comment: I guess, there's a rigidbody attached to your player. In that case, you can make **Use Gravity** to false when the player is inside the trigger.

Comment: He still walks backwards off the ladder